# what is the difference between these two function definations

Tags: javascript, performance

I was reading an article and came across this function definition

```
const circle = (radius) => {
  const proto = { 
    type: 'Circle',
  }
  return Object.assign(Object.create(proto), {radius})
}
```

why they use Object.assign, as I understand they use it for immutability
but if they use this

```
const circle = (radius) => {
  const proto = { 
    type: 'Circle',
    radius
  }
  return proto;
}
```

what is the difference? there is nothing in function definition which is  using object so why we are bothering with mutability, generally we use Object assign when we receive the object as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first function returns an object with `proto` as it's `[[Prototype]]`. So, `type` is inherited and not an *own* property of the object returned.

The second function returns an object with `type` as it's *own* property

```js
const circle = (radius) => {
  const proto = { 
    type: 'Circle',
  }
  return Object.assign(Object.create(proto), {radius})
}

const obj = circle(5);

console.log( obj.hasOwnProperty("type") ) // false 
console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).hasOwnProperty("type") ) // true
```

```js
const circle = (radius) => {
  const proto = { 
    type: 'Circle',
    radius
  }
  return proto;
}

const obj = circle(5);

console.log( obj.hasOwnProperty("type") ) // true
console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Object.prototype) // true
```

Comment: my bad I totally ignored the object. create inside object assign. thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Aside from @adiga's answer, there is a strong chance it's just a style thing. A lot of people have been writing JS for a very long time, and pick up habits without thinking about it.

If it's raw performance you care about, it's a lot faster to just create an object.

[image: benchmarks for the two functions]